# Доступ к фрагменту

Tags: android

Не могу достучать до фрагмента. Подскажите, пожалуйста, кто знает как это сделать.
Код:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.vacdetail);

            FrameLayout popUp = new FrameLayout(this);
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = 
                      new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                         FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,                           
                         FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

        popUp.setId(R.id.popUpAuthId);

        addContentView(popUp, layoutParams);
        this.getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()     
                .add(R.id.popUpAuthId, new AuthFragment(), "fragment_auth")
                .commit();

            AuthFragment fr =  (AuthFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("fragment_auth");

            ...

       Вот получается, что fr = null. Почему так? Пробовал по id получить фрагмент - результат тотже
```

Comment: Разобрался. Нужно было добавить 

    getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();

потом уже обращаться к фрагменту. Правда пока не разобрался почему было сразу  нельзя.